# WordPress: avoid using functions.php to get top level category ID for the current post

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I'm using the following two-part solution to get the post's top level category ID.

In functions.php:

```
function get_top_level_cat_id ($catid) {
while ($catid) {
$cat = get_category($catid);
$catid = $cat->category_parent;
$catparent = $cat->cat_ID; }
return $catparent; }
```

In single.php:

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$catid = $category[0]->cat_ID;
$top_level_cat_id = get_top_level_cat_id ($catid);

if ($top_level_cat_id == 1) {$type_it = "Top Level Category ID is 1";}
else {$type_it = "Top Level Category ID is not 1";}

echo $type_it;
```

It works, but using functions.php is not a good decision in my case. Putting the function, the way it should reside in functions.php, into single.php predictably ruins the output.

Is there any solution that will allow to skip using functions.php while outputting top level category ID of the current post?